# How to combined two arrays by interating with numpy?

Tags: numpy

How would you do the following?

I have these two arrays
x = [3,7,9,4,6]
y = [5,8,3,4,2]

I could like to end up with...

[[5,3],[5,7],[5,9],[5,4],[5,6],[8,3],[8,7],[8,9],[8,4],[8,6],[3,3],[3,7],[3,9],[3,4],[3,6],[4,3],[4,7],[4,9],[4,4],[4,6],[2,3],[2,7],[2,9],[2,4],[2,6]]

I was looking at np.nditer, np.repeat, and np.meshgrid and can see how I can get what I want but just wanted to find out if there is a simpler way of doing this or if you can suggest something that numpy has that would work that I probably overlooked.

Comment: Something like : `np.dstack(np.meshgrid(x,y))[...,::-1].reshape(-1,2)`. In the linked one, use : `np.meshgrid(y,x)`.

Comment: thanks, the question that you linked to "convert numpy open mesh to coordinates" has a poor title. Searching would have never turned that up.